# Can I access attributes of the first object in a list in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I’ve got a Django template that’s receiving a list of objects in the context variable `browsers`.

I want to select the first object in the list, and access one of its attributes, like this:

```
<a class="{{ browsers|first.classified_name }}" href="">{{ browsers|first }}</a>
```

However, I get a syntax error related to the attribute selection `.classified_name`.

Is there any way I can select an attribute of the first object in the list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [with-templatetag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with):

```
{% with browsers|first as first_browser %}
    {{ first_browser.classified_name }}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 9):

@lazerscience's answer is correct. Another way to achieve this is to use the index directly. For e.g.

```
{% with browsers.0 as first_browser %}
    <a class="{{ first_browser.classified_name }}" href="">{{ first_browser }}</a>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I prefer this, because `browsers.0.classified_name` can also be done

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you’re looping through the list using the `{% for %}` tag, you can ignore every object apart the first using [the `forloop.first` variable](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for), e.g.

```
{% for browser in browsers %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <a class="{{ browser.classified_name }}" href="">{{ browser }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That’s probably both less clear and less efficient though.